# Regain sudo access after nuking secondary groups

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, group

While setting up docker on Ubuntu 20.04 I did `sudo usermod -G docker $USER`. As noted in related questions here, I missed the `-a` flag and replaced all secondary groups. However, I didn't realize this until after I rebooted my machine. This is a single-user work station. I could fix this with `root`, but I don't have the password. How do I restore the proper groups without root access? The only one that causes a problem now is `sudo`, but I'm sure others will crop up. Can I do anything without reinstalling Ubuntu from scratch?

Comment: @A.B So does your suggestion mean creating a simple DOCKERFILE for an ubuntu container and then open a shell in that container?

Comment: "Else you can use the standard method of a rescue iso to recover root access." This is probably the real solution I'm looking for. Will you post an actual answer with a few more details?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/70442/158442

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You still have one group left: `docker`. That means you still have control over the docker daemon. This daemon can run a container with the host's root filesystem [mounted](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) and then the container can edit files (`vi` is available in *busybox*) or simpler: can `chroot` to the host's filesystem.

Download a minimal `busybox` image:

```
myuser@myhost:~$ docker pull busybox
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/busybox
b71f96345d44: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:930490f97e5b921535c153e0e7110d251134cc4b72bbb8133c6a5065cc68580d
Status: Downloaded newer image for busybox:latest
docker.io/library/busybox:latest
```

Run a container with this image interactively and in privileged mode (in case AppArmor would block the `chroot` command later without it):

```
$ docker run -it --mount type=bind,source=/,target=/host --privileged busybox
```

Continue with interactive commands from the container. You can simply chroot to the mount point to "enter" the root filesystem and get all Ubuntu commands:

```
/ # chroot /host
```

Use `adduser` which is a simpler wrapper around `useradd`:

```
root@74fc1b7903e5:/# adduser myuser sudo
Adding user `myuser' to group `sudo' ...
Adding user myuser to group sudo
Done.
root@74fc1b7903e5:/# exit
exit
/ # exit
```

Either logout and relog, or change group manually:

```
myuser@myhost$ sg sudo
```

And root access is restored:

```
myuser@myhost$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for myuser:
root@myhost#
```

Conclusion: be *very* prudent when allowing remote access to Docker (through port 2375/TCP). It means root access by default.

Comment: Running `docker pull` before `docker run` is not required. Docker will download the image automatically if it's missing. I think you can remove it to focus on the (awesome) solution.

Answer (score 7):

> Can I do anything without reinstalling Ubuntu from scratch?

Aside from the docker-specific method given in the other answer, if you have physical access and there are not countermeasures* in place then you can nearly always get into a system if you are prepared to reboot it.

There are a couple common methods.

One is to use a livecd and mount the filesystem.

Another is to use the "init=/bin/sh" trick, when you get the grub menu select your boot option but instead of pressing enter you press "e", then you add "init=/bin/sh" to the kernel command line. This should drop you to a shell early in the boot process. The root file system is probablly still read only at this point so do `mount -o remount,rw /` to make it writable. You should then be able to set a root password with `passwd root` or add a user to the sudo group by using `adduser myuser sudo`. When you have finished making your edits you can then do `exec init` to continue the boot process as normal.

* bios/bootloader passwords would be one, some types disk encryption may be another.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.